# Create a bidimensional table in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to create a bidimensional table to link 2 lists, with this form:

```
<p:dataTable var="valuelist1" value="#{bean.list1}">
<p:column headerText="" styleClass="ui-widget-header">
    <h:outputText value="#{valuelist1.name}"/>
</p:column>

  <ui:repeat var="valuelist2" value="#{bean.list2}" >
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{valuelist2.name}"/>
    </p:column>
</ui:repeat>
</p:dataTable>
```

But I don't get create columns with the list2, all the occurrences appear in the same table, don't appear in new differents columns of each one.

What's is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to create a dynamic datatable in JSF (or primefaces)?

Comment: Yes, to link 2 lists.

Comment: You should investigate how to do that on stackoverflow.

Comment: whit <p:columns> ?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but try to put a datatable inside a datatable!!